# The browser is using sans-serif even though Arial is available

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

I'm working on a Wordpress website and from the console I can see that the font family for the text in the menu is `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`.

However it is rendering the text in sans-serif instead of Arial. That suggests, that the font `Arial` is not available in my browser, but when I adjust the css right in the console and change the `font-family` to `font-family: Arial` I see  the text in `Arial`, and I am sure that it's Arial because I'm comparing it next to an image I did through Photoshop that contains Arial text.

Why doesn't my browser render Arial even though it's the first option and instead renders sans-serif?

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Arial';
}
.other{
  font-family: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
}
```

```html
This text should be Arial.
  <b>  Home Services Careers Feedback Privacy Policy Referral </b>
  <br>
  <span class="other">This text can be Arial sans-serif or Helvatica </span>
  <b class="other">  Home Services Careers Feedback Privacy Policy Referral </b>
```

Comment: I suspect something isn't what you think. Perhaps you could make a [mcve]?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I was able to replicate it and have added it in the question.

Comment: Typo: `font-family: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';` You don't quote the list, you quote individual font names, but that's only needed if they have have a space in the name itself. `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;` works fine.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara actually in the fiddle that fixed it... so I guess that's what I need to modify by hardcoding it in wordpress. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you people giving me -s?

Comment: @NaguibIhab if there is no code in your question, update your question - having a jsfiddle is fine, but also show the pertinent details in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, because you have added everything inside single quotes. The browser tries to search for `'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'` but no font with such name exists, so it reverts to default, which is usually `"Times New Roman", "Times", serif`, disregarding what did you specify for the document earlier.

The correct definition should be:

```
.other{
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}
```

Note that the font names are in quotes, *each*. The font types doesn't need to be specified in quotes and it has to be last in the list so it doesn't mess you up.

The browser looks for fonts in the order you specify them and applies the one it finds first. If no specific font is found, and the font type is specified, the browser will pick one from the visitor's system.

Comment: no idea, but you don't quote font family names unless they have special characters in them, so it's technically just `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif` in this case. No quotes unless there are spaces in the name, or non-hyphen symbols.

Comment: Went on the safe side and wanted to explain how the OP should have been proceeding, if he used quotes.